# Filter group by many2many field in tree view Odoo 8?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-8

In CRM module, I am trying to set a filter group_by to many2many field, but i've received this error :

> AssertionError: Fields in 'groupby' must be regular database-persisted fields (no function or related fields), or function fields with store=True

the field is 'categ_ids'
This the code py and xml:

```
'write_date': fields.datetime('Update Date', readonly=True),
'categ_ids': fields.many2many('crm.case.categ', 'crm_lead_category_rel', 'lead_id', 'category_id', 'Tags', \
    domain="['|', ('section_id', '=', section_id), ('section_id', '=', False), ('object_id.model', '=', 'crm.lead')]", help="Classify and analyze your lead/opportunity categories like: Training, Service"),
'contact_name': fields.char('Contact Name', size=64),
```

For xml :

```
    <filter string="Service" domain="[]" context="{'group_by':'categ_ids'}"/>
```

Thank advance

Answer (score 1):

The field `categ_ids` is a related field (many2many). The error is saying that you can NOT use a related field for a group by function.

Comment: Then there is no way to do group_by to this field

Comment: You need to group_by a field that is held in the database in your model. You could use a computed field and use store=True however if your data changes on your related model you will need to have a function which keeps the value of your computed field current.

Comment: Have you an example

Comment: Sorry, I do not have time at the moment to prepare an example and have not done this in practice. But to my knowledge you can not group by a related field.

Comment: Just i want an existing example, and thank you for your help

Comment: I hear you. I am not sure where the group by function is called on a many2many field or a field that has been computed and stored on the current model. Many2one would have been easier to create an example. You could just create a stored computed field. Many2many is complicated and I do not know of an example. There may be one, I just do not know.  Sorry, wish I could be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much @phillipstack

Answer (score 1):

```
M2M_name_field = fields.Char(related='M2M.name', store=True, string='M2M Name')

<filter string="M2M Name" domain="[]" context="{'group_by':'M2M_name_field '}"/>
```

y problem el problema

Comment: post should be in english